# Evaluating $\iint xy\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$ over an elliptical disk

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$I=\iint_A xy\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$ where $$A=\{(x,y): ax^2+2hxy+by^2\le r^2, a>0, ab-h^2>0\}$$

I tried diagonalising the quadratic form $h(x,y)=ax^2+2hxy+by^2$ to some

$$g(u,v)=u^2+v^2$$

where

$$\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{a} &  \frac{h}{\sqrt{a}}\\\ 0 &  \sqrt{\frac{ab-h^2}{a}} \\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$$

The Jacobian of the transformation $(x,y)\to(u,v)$ is

$$\det(J) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ab-h^2}}$$

The integral then reduces to

$$I=\iint_{u^2+v^2\le r^2}\left(\frac{uv}{\sqrt{ab-h^2}}-\frac{hv^2}{ab-h^2}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{ab-h^2}}\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v$$

Now I could apply a polar transformation to get the answer. But this method seems a bit cumbersome, especially solving for $x$ and $y$ from $u,v$. Is there an obvious alternate solution?

The problem can also be seen as finding $\mathbb{E}(XY)$ where $(X,Y)$ is jointly uniform over $A$.

**EDIT.**

Proceeding in the way I have done so far, I get the final answer as

$$I=-\frac{\pi r^4h}{4(ab-h^2)^{3/2}}$$

Is this indeed the correct answer?

Comment: That seems like the natural way of doing it. Solving for $x$ and $y$ is quick if you use $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad-bc} \begin{pmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, When I said $J$ is the Jacobian, I meant it as the determinant itself. I assume you added $|J|$ to mean the determinant of $J$. I would use that to mean the absolute value of $J$, which in this case is the same as $J$.

Comment: Using a capital letter to denote a scalar is bad notation, imho.

Comment: @HansLundmark Would you recommend doing the same to evaluate $\iint_A x\,dx\,dy$?

Comment: No, in that case the integral is obviously zero by symmetry (since $(-x,-y)\in A \iff (x,y) \in A$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer in my post is correct, as I was able to verify using *Mathematica* [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170663/using-mathematica-to-evaluate-iint-xy-mathrmdx-mathrmdy-over-an-ellip).